# how do i get value from listview

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` with my `sqlite` data and i would like to click and display the value in another `Activity`.

Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Below is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = mydb.queueAll();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { myDbAdapter.ELDERLY_DATE_TIME };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.displayactivity, cursor, from, to);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    mydb.close();

    listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where do you want to display the information? In another Activity, a popup window, a Toast, etc? **Also** exactly what information do you want to display?

Comment: http://mobile.dzone.com/news/listview-data-sqlitedatabase

Comment: actually i just want to get the value so that i can past the value to another activity through intent

Comment: Why do you have another `Activity` for showing the value chosen?

Answer (score 0):

> actually i just want to get the value so that i can past the value to
>   another activity through intent

You do not have to "pass" the value to another `Activity`. Inside your other `Activity` you just query for the correct value that was selected in your `ListView`.

Comment: actually i going to use the value to get other information from sqlite database and display it on the activity

Comment: You need to pass some identification to the other `Activity` that identifies which item in the `ListView` was selected, with `Intents`. And then the other `Activity` would query the `sqlite` table for the value. But if you could explain why you need to pass this to another `Intent`, there might be a better way to do this in general.

Comment: how am i able to do it? cuase im new to this.. right now i have list view populate data from sqlite

Comment: Here are a couple references that talk about passing data to another `Activity` with `Intents`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: i know how to pass value through intent. But i not too sure how to get value from my listview.

Comment: `onClickListener` gives you a `position` of the `View` that was pressed. This is the item selected. Use that `position` to determine what item was pressed in your `Adapter` and then use that to determine the id you need to use in the other `Activity` to get it from the database.